# How to get the value of $translate json file for specific language

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a components that using translation:

```
 .config(function($translateProvider) {
     $translateProvider
        .preferredLanguage('en_US')
        .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape')
        .translations('en_US', {
            '<%=projectName%>': {
                'name': {
                    'first': 'Luke',
                    'last': 'Skywalker'
                }
            }
        })
```

I want to get that json string so I run the follwoing commands:

```
var tmp = $translateProvider.translations();
```

In that way I get the json string into tmp variable

How can I do the same if my json is loaded from file:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '../assets/strings/strings_',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(window.niceSaasWfm.appConfiguration.defaultLang);

var tmp = $translateProvider.translations();
```

Now tmp.en_US variable is empty.